# Node.js Firebase Function sending Base64 image to External API

Tags: node.js, firebase, base64, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I’m using Firebase Functions with a Storage trigger in Node.js to send uploaded image data to an external API endpoint where photos are uploaded.

I’m currently taking images uploaded to a bucket in my Firebase storage, converting them to base64 strings, and plug them into my dictionary for the request.

My current issue is that seems like the dictionary is being cut short. I looked at the console logs on the Firebase console and seems like it ends after the base64 variable.

I’m not sure whether this is a bug with the syntax, or with the way I’m using the base64, or with Firebase Functions. If anyone knows what might be going on, please let me know.

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const firebase = require('firebase');

exports.identifyUpdate = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {

    const fileBucket = object.bucket;
    const filePath = object.name;
    const contentType = object.contentType;
    const fileName = path.basename(filePath);

    if(!filePath.substring(0,filePath.indexOf('/')) == 'updates') {
        console.log("Triggered by non-update photo")
        return null;
    }

    console.log("Update photo added")

    // Create Firebase app (for Realtime Database access)

    var config = {
        apiKey: "[apikey]",
        authDomain: "[PROJECT_ID].firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com",
    };

    if(!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }

    // Trace back to Update stored in Realtime Database

    const database = firebase.database().ref()
    const pendingRef = database.child('pendingUpdates')

    console.log(filePath)

    const splitPath = filePath.split(path.sep)

    const patientID = splitPath[1]
    console.log('Patient ID: ' + patientID)

    const updateID = splitPath[2]
    console.log('Update ID: ' + updateID)

    const updateRef = pendingRef.child(patientID).child(updateID)

    console.log('Found Update reference')

    const photoRef = updateRef.child('photoURLs').child(fileName)

    console.log('Photo Reference: ' + photoRef)

    // Download and convert image to base64

    const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket)
    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName)
    const metadata = {
        contentType: contentType
    };

    var base64;

    return bucket.file(filePath).download({
        destination: tempFilePath
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath)
    }).then(() => {

        base64 = base64_encode(tempFilePath)
        console.log("Base 64: " + base64)

    }).then(() => {
    // Send image data to Kairos

        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            uri: 'https://api.kairos.com/recognize',
            body: {
                'image': base64,
                'gallery_name': 'gallerytest1'
            },
            headers: {
                'app_id': '[id]',
                'app_key': '[key]'
            },
            json: true
        }

        return new Promise (() => {
            console.log(options)
            request(options)
            .then(function(repos) {

                console.log('API call succeeded');

                console.log('Kairos response: ' + repos);

                const apiResult = repos['images']['transaction']['subject_id']
                console.log("Transaction " + JSON.stringify(apiResult))

            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('API call failed')
            })
        });

    })

    // Delete app instance (to prevent concurrency leaks)

    const deleteApp = () => app.delete().catch(() => null);
    deleteApp.call

})

function base64_encode(file) {
    // read binary data
    var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
    return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}
```

Image Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: `const apiResult = repos['images']['transaction']['subject_id']` probably throws an error.  Do you know what [Kairos' error responses](https://kairos.com/docs/api/error-codes) are? They seem to all be 200. Perhaps if instead of `console.log('API call failed')` you called `console.log(err)` you could get more information

Comment: Just realized that ['images']['transaction']['subject_id'] wasn't the correct path for the information I was trying to get. Thanks for the suggestion @JamesPoag! I didn't see what my mistake was until I printing the error.